# Show that $T_{ijk}V_k$ is a second rank tensor in 3D space

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, tensor-rank

The task is show that $$T_{ijk}V_k$$ is a rank-2 tensor.

---

Using $$T_{ijk} = a_{i\alpha}a_{j\beta}a_{k\gamma}T_{\alpha\beta\gamma}' $$
and
$$V_{k} = a_{k\gamma}V_{\gamma}' $$

I arrive at

$$T_{ijk}V_k = a_{i\alpha}a_{j\beta}a_{k\gamma}T_{\alpha\beta\gamma}'a_{k\gamma}V_{\gamma}'$$

I think the key is to show that $$(a_{k\gamma})^2 = \delta^{k}_{\gamma}$$

but I can't think of how it would work. To me it seems that $$(a_{k\gamma})^2 = 3 $$  which I get from the orthonormality of the rows/columns (with  other rows/columns) of the rotation matrices (I'm working in 3D cartesian space) and the double sum over $k$ and $\gamma$, which then gives a (seemingly out of place) factor of 3.

If someone could explain what I'm missing or the correct method to show this, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get only one $\gamma$. For the transformation of the second $k$ you need another, independent index. So
$$
T_{ijk}V_k = a_{i\alpha}a_{j\beta}a_{k\gamma}T_{\alpha\beta\gamma}'a_{k\eta}V_{\eta}'.
$$
Now use that the metric used is euclidean and that the transformation matrix is orthogonal to get
$$
a_{k\gamma}a_{k\eta}=\delta_{\gamma\eta}.
$$

As a result, only the actually free indices get transformed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Why do I need a different index for the vector? I am a bit confused about when you need to give an object a different index

Comment: Precisely to avoid the misunderstanding that you fell for. It is ok to have the same index if you have factors that are sums, $(\sum_\gamma A_\gamma)\cdot(\sum_\gamma B_\gamma)$. However, if you rewrite this as a double sum, you need distinct indices to get the same expression, $\sum_\gamma\sum_\eta A_\gamma B_\eta$.